# Organize Data that is Callable to Hovertool

Tags: python, pandas, hover, pivot-table, ordereddictionary

I'm confused how to make the hover tool call the two main variables of my stacked bar plot.

My pivot_table is below. The company names are the first column, and the months are along the top row. The number is the Number of Calls in that month from each customer.

```
pivot_table.head(2)
Out[4]: 
Month                              1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  CompanyName                                                                     
Company1     17  30  29  39  15  27  23  12  36  21  18   
Company2   4  11  13  22  34  27  16  18  29  31  17   

Month                              12  
CompanyName                            
Company1     15  
Company2     14
```

Here is my code

```
# get the months
Jan = pivot_table[1].astype(float).values
Feb = pivot_table[2].astype(float).values
Mar = pivot_table[3].astype(float).values
Apr = pivot_table[4].astype(float).values
May = pivot_table[5].astype(float).values
Jun = pivot_table[6].astype(float).values
Jul = pivot_table[7].astype(float).values
Aug = pivot_table[8].astype(float).values
Sep = pivot_table[9].astype(float).values
Oct = pivot_table[10].astype(float).values
Nov = pivot_table[11].astype(float).values
Dec = pivot_table[12].astype(float).values
# build a dict containing the grouped data

months = OrderedDict([('Jan', Jan), ('Feb', Feb), ('Mar', Mar), ('Apr',Apr), ('May',May), ('Jun',Jun),('Jul',Jul), ('Aug',Aug), ('Sep',Sep),('Oct',Oct),('Nov',Nov),('Dec',Dec)])




hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("Month", "@months"),
        ("Number of Calls", ""),
        ]
)
output_file("stacked_bar.html")
bar = Bar(months, Companies, title="Stacked bars", legend = "top_right", width = 1200, height=900, stacked=True)
bar.add_tools(hover)

show(bar)
```

The part where I'm not sure how to call the variables is this:

```
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("Month", ""),
        ("Number of Calls", ""),
        ]
)
```

I've tried making a big list for the Number of Calls part this way: `NumberCalls = pivot_table.stack().astype(int).tolist()` I know Bar doesn't support ColumnDataSource, which is what I've used before. I've tried calling "@months" but it's an Ordereddict so it's not calling right. Bonus if there is a way to get the months in a loop rather than one by one!